# which ethernet interface I'm using

Tags: 14.04, networking, ethernet

I'm confused about the ethernet hardware on my machine, I'm using ubuntu 14.04, with command `lshw -C network` I got the following output:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network:0             
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: BCM57840 NetXtreme II 10 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: p6p1
       version: 11
       serial: 78:24:af:85:3c:5c
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bnx2x driverversion=1.78.17-0 duplex=full firmware=bc 7.8.79 ip=192.168.0.196 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:42 memory:dc000000-dc7fffff memory:db800000-dbffffff memory:dc810000-dc81ffff memory:fb780000-fb7fffff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: BCM57840 NetXtreme II 10 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       logical name: p6p2
       version: 11
       serial: 78:24:af:85:3c:5e
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical fibre 1000bt-fd
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bnx2x driverversion=1.78.17-0 firmware=bc 7.8.79 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=fibre
       resources: irq:45 memory:db000000-db7fffff memory:da800000-daffffff memory:dc800000-dc80ffff memory:fb700000-fb77ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: em1
       version: 06
       serial: 10:c3:7b:46:c4:7b
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:82 memory:f7100000-f711ffff memory:f7128000-f7128fff ioport:f040(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0d:00.0
       logical name: p7p1
       version: 00
       serial: 10:c3:7b:46:14:41
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k firmware=2.1-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:19 memory:fb200000-fb21ffff ioport:9000(size=32) memory:fb220000-fb223fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

but I really dont know how to interpret the output, does it mean I have multiple ethernet adapters on the machine? but how can I tell which one I'm using now?

I observe there is `BCM57840 NetXtreme II 10 Gigabit Ethernet` but the capacity is only `1Gbit/s`, does it mean I have not reach the optimal speed? how can tune it?

ADD: with `ifconfig` I got

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:c3:7b:46:c4:7b  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:f7100000-f7120000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:118394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:118394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2538318861 (2.5 GB)  TX bytes:2538318861 (2.5 GB)

p6p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:24:af:85:3c:5c  
          inet addr:192.168.0.196  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7a24:afff:fe85:3c5c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:179256971 errors:5665 dropped:0 overruns:5665 frame:0
          TX packets:170144980 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:210860777033 (210.8 GB)  TX bytes:147913380482 (147.9 GB)
          Interrupt:42 Memory:dc000000-dc7fffff 

p6p2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 78:24:af:85:3c:5e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:45 Memory:db000000-db7fffff 

p7p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:c3:7b:46:14:41  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 Memory:fb200000-fb220000
```

but which one is active?

Comment: It looks like you have 2 10 Gbit interfaces, and 2 1Gbit interfaces. Try to run `ifconfig` to see which interface is active and it's configuration, and `ifconfig -a` to see all interfaces. Also you could look at the back of your server ;-)

Comment: @SorenA Thank you, pls see my `ifconfig` output

Comment: The routing table determines which network interface to select.

Comment: Only the interface called `p6p1` is configured, so it is probably the only one connected. It is a 10 Gbit NIC, but what kind of SFP is mounted in the NIC ? Maybe `ethtool p6p1` can tell you more.